# How to use HKWorkoutRouteQuery on iOS 11

Tags: ios, swift, ios11, healthkit

Does anyone know how to use HKWorkoutRouteQuery on iOS 11?  For some reason the constructor found here [HKWorkoutRouteQuery](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkworkoutroutequery/2873797-init) does not appear to be available.

I *can* however use it in a WatchOS application/extension.

I'm using the example code from the WWDC 2017 presentation found [here](https://devstreaming-cdn.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2017/221izy8b17y2dtiy/221/221_whats_new_in_health.pdf).

Anyone have success with this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution, I needed to include MapKit.  Which seems to make sense because the constructor includes a CLLocation.